# How to improve visibility of a black and white plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm plotting information from 10 sets in the same plot. The result is very messy since the lines for each game intersect and overlap with each other, and the width of the final image is small. Here's the image:

[image]

And here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$jogada$, ylabel=$tempo(ms)$]
    \addplot coordinates {
(1,8989)(2,9013)(3,9013)(4,9018)(5,9023)(6,9026)(7,9059)(8,9064)(9,9096)

(1,8998)(2,9002)(3,9002)(4,9003)(5,9006)(6,9010)(7,9013)(8,9022)(9,9025)(10,9025)(11,9025)(12,9045)(13,9057)(14,9083)

(1,8988)(2,9005)(3,9008)(4,9012)(5,9029)(6,9034)(7,9037)(8,9060)(9,9070)(10,9238)

(1,8991)(2,8998)(3,9005)(4,9012)(5,9012)(6,9013)(7,9020)(8,9035)(9,9042)(10,9050)(11,9068)(12,9095)

(1,9021)(2,9042)(3,9054)(4,9127)(5,9211)(6,9244)

(1,9007)(2,9031)(3,9044)(4,9046)(5,9063)

(1,8995)(2,8996)(3,9008)(4,9011)(5,9019)(6,9021)(7,9024)(8,9046)(9,9086)(10,9134)

(1,9006)(2,9015)(3,9032)(4,9070)(5,9071)

(1,8997)(2,8998)(3,9006)(4,9020)(5,9023)(6,9024)(7,9026)(8,9030)(9,9032)(10,9041)(11,9072)(12,9083)(13,9086)(14,9191)

(1,9018)(2,9028)(3,9039)(4,9040)(5,9050)(6,9062)(7,9077)(8,9080)(9,9097)(10,9117)
};
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Componentes do \textit{Game Manager} e sua comunicação com jogadores} \label{montecarlotemposmedios1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I improve the legibility and visibility of this plot, so that it doesn't look so crunched up and messy? The final plot will be black and white.

Comment: unrelated to your lines but don't do `$tempo(ms)$` !! never use math italic for multi-letter words. _If_ you want italic then `\textit{tempo(ms)}` or `\textit{tempo}(\textit{ms})`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not make use of `pgfplots`'s cycle list feature which automatically chooses another line- and pointstyle, as well as another color for each line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={jogada}, ylabel={tempo (\si{\milli\second})}]
      \addplot coordinates {(1,8989)(2,9013)(3,9013)(4,9018)(5,9023)(6,9026)(7,9059)(8,9064)(9,9096)};
      \addplot coordinates {(1,8998)(2,9002)(3,9002)(4,9003)(5,9006)(6,9010)(7,9013)(8,9022)(9,9025)(10,9025)(11,9025)(12,9045)(13,9057)(14,9083)};
      \addplot coordinates {(1,8988)(2,9005)(3,9008)(4,9012)(5,9029)(6,9034)(7,9037)(8,9060)(9,9070)(10,9238)};
      \addplot coordinates {(1,8991)(2,8998)(3,9005)(4,9012)(5,9012)(6,9013)(7,9020)(8,9035)(9,9042)(10,9050)(11,9068)(12,9095)};
      \addplot coordinates {(1,9021)(2,9042)(3,9054)(4,9127)(5,9211)(6,9244)};
      \addplot coordinates {(1,9007)(2,9031)(3,9044)(4,9046)(5,9063)};
      \addplot coordinates {(1,8995)(2,8996)(3,9008)(4,9011)(5,9019)(6,9021)(7,9024)(8,9046)(9,9086)(10,9134)};
      \addplot coordinates {(1,9006)(2,9015)(3,9032)(4,9070)(5,9071)};
      \addplot coordinates {(1,8997)(2,8998)(3,9006)(4,9020)(5,9023)(6,9024)(7,9026)(8,9030)(9,9032)(10,9041)(11,9072)(12,9083)(13,9086)(14,9191)};
      \addplot coordinates {(1,9018)(2,9028)(3,9039)(4,9040)(5,9050)(6,9062)(7,9077)(8,9080)(9,9097)(10,9117)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Componentes do \textit{Game Manager} e sua comunicação com jogadores}
  \label{fig:montecarlotemposmedios1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]